# CSS/HTML Loading bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this jQuery code

```
function SetFilesNeeded( needed ) {
$("#neededFiles").text(needed);
}
function SetFilesTotal( total ) {
$("#totalFiles").text(total);
}
```

The `SetFilesNedded` function is how many files are needed, it is called every time the value `needed` changes. The `SetFilesTotal` is the total number of files.

I want to make a loading bar with a width of 580px. My CSS loading bar:

```
#loadBar2 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #99FF99;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 580px;
    height: 10px;
    top: -823px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -290px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: relative;

    opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity = 50);
}
```

How would I use the jQuery code set the starting width to 1px, and when more files are added, the bar width is increased until it reaches the maximum (580px)?

Comment: Could you please post your html as well, or a fiddle would be even better

Comment: Choose the answer that helped you out

Answer (score 2):

You dont need any plugin to create simple loading bar.

[Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bx0273ro/](http://jsfiddle.net/bx0273ro/)

It's basically two divs, one is parent which is used as background and then child which is used as color part of progress part.

The width of the bar is actually simply just this:

**`MaxWidth * ((total-needed)/total)`**

Here is some code animating it

```
var needed, total, 
    tEle = $('#totalFiles'), 
    nEle = $('#neededFiles'),
    bar = $('#loadingBar'),
    width = bar.width();

needed = total = tEle.text();

var t = setInterval(function(){
    if (--needed == 0) clearInterval(t);
    update();
},500);

function update() {
    nEle.text(needed);
    bar.find('.bar').width(width * ((total-needed)/total));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need that functionality I would suggest this jQuery loading bar plugin.
https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress

That is very nice and quick solution. Code is open source on github so you can see how it is implemented.  Also on git you can find quick instruction how to set up plugin.

If you stuck somewhere feel free to ask.